# GWT : logic of my application embeded in the ui interface?

Tags: javascript, security, gwt

I have a question about GWT. I know that (I suppose it's correct) logic of an application written with GWT is uploaded to client UI. So everyone can see how I "coded" and all my algorithms  (it's javascript) !!! then concurrent enterprises could cheat my algorithms !!

I want to know if there a built-in secure  mecanism in GWT to avoid that.

Thanks

Comment: I have to agree with the answer from pejot if you really want to protect your algorithms. @Baadshah is correct in saying that the JavaScript is obfuscated, but that doesn't prevent reverse engineering, it just makes it more work. If you keep the algorithms that you really care about on the server, as suggested by pejot, then you can ensure that no one can "steal" your algorithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't worry,GWT Takes care of it.**

> By default, GWT obfuscates the JavaScript it produces. This is partly done to protect the intellectual property of the application you develop, but also because obfuscation reduces the size of the generated JavaScript files, making them faster to download and parse.

[Why is my GWT-generated JavaScript gibberish?](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5/wiki/FAQ_JavaScriptGibberish)

However,if you want to make your code human readable you can [compile](http://css.dzone.com/news/understanding-gwt-compiler) with  `style -PRETTY` .

Answer (score 1):

I don't agree. I think logic stays on the server side and it's invoke as a callback for events generated by user interface (of course if you code your application well.) If you fallow this https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/mvp-architecture you will have logic and UI separated. Anyway js generated by GWT is not humanreadable (not sure if there a tools to convert it to humanreadable instance).